# How to check what symbolic links are used in a folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, ntfs, symlink

I've been looking at the [Windows 7 symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) (using mklink) [Edit - they are also supported on Windows Vista, [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003), [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008)]. Is it possible to programmatically determine if a folder is a symlink?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this at serverfault

Comment: Derek: Why? If I may ask. What this has to do with administering servers instead of programming eludes me.

Comment: Most important detail of all: Using what programming language?

Comment: @OMG Ponies, shouldn't really matter, its the winapi I was curious about, but C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx) and check for [FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332330(VS.85).aspx).

**ETA:** Since you clarified now that you're doing this from C#, you can do this natively there:

```
System.IO.File.GetAttributes("some/path")
```

You can check for the ReparsePoint flag in the returned enum value.